# Why use extra procedure to initialize values instead of doing it in constructor?

Tags: oracle, oop, plsql

So i've been going trough types at my new work and they pretty much all look like this

```
create or replace TYPE BODY T_Some_Type AS

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION T_Some_Type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT AS
  BEGIN
    INTIALIZE();
    RETURN;
  END T_Some_Type;

  MEMBER PROCEDURE INTIALIZE AS
  BEGIN
    var1 := 0;
    var2 := 0;
    var3 := 0;
  END INTIALIZE;
END;
```

Being skilled in OOP but new to pl/sql, i keep wondering why use extra procedure to initialize variables, when it can be done directly in constructor making objects interface simpler and lighter on memory.
This is how i would normally do it :

```
create or replace TYPE BODY T_Some_Type AS

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION T_Some_Type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT AS
  BEGIN
    var1 := 0;
    var2 := 0;
    var3 := 0;

    RETURN;
  END T_Some_Type;
END;
```

Is there any advantage or this is recommended for some reason?
Please advise.

Comment: Maybe they want to be able to re-initialize the object later by calling `initialize`?

Comment: Wouldnt i be able to invoke contructor code again by just setting the object to new object? like when i initialized it 1st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear in mind that the object features in Oracle have evolved slowly since version 8.0, and yet are still pretty limited in some respects.  This is because Oracle is a relational database with a structured and procedural programming paradigm: object-orientation is not a good fit.

So.  In a language like Java we can override a method in a sub-type but execute the code in the parent's implementation with a `super()` call.

Before 11g Oracle had no similar mechanism for extending member functions.  If we wanted to override a super-type's method we had to duplicate the code in the sub-type, which was pretty naff.  There was a workaround which is not much less naff: extract the common code into a separate method in the super-type, and call that method in the super- type and its dependents.

In 11g Oracle introduced "Generalized Invocation".  This allows us to call super-type code on a sub-type.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#CHDFBDBI). There is one major limitation with Generalized Invocation, and that is that we cannot use it with Constructor methods.  Therefore, in its sub-types' constructors too our only choice is to put that code in a method like the `initialize()` in your question.

Comment: Wouldnt i be able to invoke contructor code again by just setting the object to new object? like when i initialized it 1st